# Javascript - regular expressions with a prefix followed by 6 numbers

Tags: javascript

below is a my attempt at a function to validate a form field with the prefix ZHA or zha followed by 6 numbers. The prefix part seems to be working but if I enter 1 number it still validates. Any suggestions?

```
function checkHnum(hnumvalue){
    var authTest = /^[ZHA]|[zha]+[\d]{6}$/;
    return authTest.test(hnumvalue)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a test case for the false positive? The cominations I tested all worked for me: `zha1`, `1`, `zha123456`

Comment: How about `Zha`, `zHa` etc?

Comment: if (hnum == "" || !checkHnum(hnum)){
  hideErrors();
  document.getElementById("errAuthNum").style.display = "inline";
  return false;

Comment: You should look up what `[]` does: it's not what you think.

Comment: damn you thg435 :) never thought of that. Now I really am stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex **doesn't** accept 1 digit only but it's buggy as it, for example, doesn't constraint the order of the letters (`[ZHA]` is "Z or H or A"). You seem to want

```
var ok = /^(ZHA|zha)\d{6}$/.test(yourString)
```

Note that if you also want to accept `"Zha123456"` then you can simply use a case insensitive regular expression :

```
var ok = /^zha\d{6}$/i.test(yourString)
```

Comment: Thanks dystroy and Edgar works perfectly. Looking into why I was wrong now. Any advice on a good resource for regular expressions?

Comment: Nice one centurian like it, like it.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be:

```
/^ZHA\d{6}$/i
```

Note the `i` to make it case insensitive.  The problem with yours was mainly the brackets. The brackets match one of the characters that inside of it.

For example
   `[ZHA]` will match `Z`, or `H`, or `A`, but not the full `ZHA`

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Technically, this doesn't exactly answer the question.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to understand his purpose more than answering "exactly" what he asks

Comment: And it's wrong if you take the question literally. You're also not explaining why his attempt failed.

Comment: Exactly, I agree with Lightness